# Swift - Structuring Firebase data for chat app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am actually working on a chat app using Swift and Firebase and I am having some issues when fetching existing data and new data.

1. My first question is since Firebase does fetch every new and already existing data when observing using .childAdded (designed by default), when a new user has been added to an existing chat with already existing messages with it, how do I tell the app to only fetch new messages? Because the new added user shouldn't fetch the old existing messages.

I thought about using a timestamp for the time the user was added and filter by it but is it a good way to fetch all the data and filter?

2. The second one is similar to the first one, I made my app to clear all the data when logging out and to fetch the data related with that user when logging in. I am currently using the same observer for the data to fetch when logging in and for the new messages. In this situation I am not able to tell if the message is an existing message or a new message which I need to set the right app icon badge number of unread new messages.

Should I just use a different observer for those two situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for you first problem you can use firebase query

```
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: messageTime).queryStarting(atValue: timeUserAdded, childKey: messageTime )
query.observe(of: .childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

 )}
```

and for the second problem

you can save last seen message time (i.e. like WhatsApp does with time) and can show any messages after that time as a new message.

Hope this helps, ask if you have any confusion.

Comment: thank you I didn't know they had something like queryOrdered or query Starting I should have looked into their documentation I am an idiot hahah anyways thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Also I have one more question I am using Coredata to store data that I fetch from Firebase like users, chats, messages and whenever I get a new message I use arrayOfChats.contains(where: {}) to check whether I already stored it or not I am doing it this way because I need to reload all the data whenever a user log in so I was wondering if this was a good idea

Comment: You should have offline copy of data to instantaneously show it to the user. And if you implemented the coredata completely that okay. But firebase also provides offfline capability, which i have not used it yet so not sure i effectively it work.